# Checking whether the Raspberry pi is communicating over the ethernet cable

Tags: camera

I connected a camera to my Raspberry Pi 4 over the ethernet cable and I do not know whether the camera is even communicating with the Raspberry. Is there any way that I can check (through terminal) if the Raspberry is able to communicate with the camera?

Comment: I do not understand what you have done.  Could you edit your question and add a diagram and photos showing how the Pi and camera and ethernet  are connected.

Comment: Connect both the camera and the Raspberry Pi to a router. The router will assign IP addresses to both the devices. Then you will be able use the Pi to see the camera.